# Convertir método Datatable a Lista genérica

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework code firts en una app Windows Forms, tengo la necesidad de hacer esto:

```
public static DataTable SelectDT(PersonalCriteria filter)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = Conexion.Conectar("default"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Codigo AS Código, Nombre AS Descripción FROM Personal
                WHERE((@Codigo IS NULL) OR (Codigo LIKE '%' + @Codigo + '%'))
                AND ((@Nombre IS NULL) OR (Nombre LIKE '%' + @Nombre + '%'))";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Codigo)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : filter.Codigo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Nombre)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : filter.Nombre);
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Como lo haría usando linq, tengo mi Contex.

Si hago el método que sugiere @LeandroTuttini con una lista, podría hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo una DataTable declarado a nivel de formulario para poder usarlo en el método txtDescripcion_TextChanged

```
case 112: // Cliente
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    ClienteCriteria filter = new ClienteCriteria()
                    {
                        Codigo = Helper.DatosTablaInputbox.Valor,
                    };
                    dt = Cliente.SelectDT(filter);
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    dgvBusqueda.DataSource = dt;
                    FormatoGrilla();
                }
```

Método, TextChanged

```
private void txtDescripcion_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fieldName = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = fieldName;
        DataView view = dt.DefaultView;
        view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        if (txtDescripcion.Text != string.Empty)
            view.RowFilter = fieldName + " LIKE '%" + txtDescripcion.Text + "%'";
        dgvBusqueda.DataSource = view;
    }
```

Lo que hago es cargar el DataGridView con datos con el método que convertistes a Linq, una vez cargados lo que hago es filtrar en el objeto DGV.

Se podría hacer con una lista genérica o un IEnumerable reemplazar todo, una vez intente hacerlo pero no pude en la parte del evento del TextBox.

Comment: Buenos días acabo de re formular mi pregunta, espero ya no este en espera

Comment: Desde un principio mi pregunta a estado bien formulada, si no Leandro no hubiera respondido acertadamente o el problema va por otro sentido que Leandro puede responder y ustedes no, de todas maneras gracias ya pude solucionar mi problema, gracias Leandro por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo sin problemas armanndo una estructura similar pero con los parametros como nulos para permitir que sean opcionales

```
public List<Personal> GetPersonal(int? codigo, string nombre)
{
    using(DbContext context = new DbContext())
    {
        var result = (from p in context.Personal
                     where ((!codigo.HasValue) || (p.Codigo.Contains(codigo.Value)))
                            && ((nombre == null) || (p.Nombre.Contains(nombre)))
                     select p).ToList();;

        return result;
    }
}
```

**>>quiero usar un DataTable se puede?**

podrias usar el `CopyToDataTable()` para convertir la clase

[Cómo implementar CopyToDataTable donde el tipo genérico T no es un objeto DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Leandro, por esta vez quiero usar un DataTable se puede?

Comment: podrias usar el CopyToDataTable()

Comment: Leandro modifique la pregunta.